# How to use a class as a key of a map when the class contains a 2d array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, hashmap, c++14

I have a class which looks like the following:

```
class A{
   private:
   int *a[10];
};
```

Now I want to have a map which will have the mentioned class as it's key.

```
map<A,int> visited;
```

How can I overload the less operator/write a compare function here so that the map can identify duplicate 2D arrays? I have written a overloader inside the class. But, it's treating objects containing duplicate arrays as different objects. This is the function I have written:

```
bool operator<(const A& other) const{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(a[i][j]!=other.a[i][j])return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

I can't find the problem in the code. Can somebody please help?

Comment: != is not <. Your operator< is broken.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it then? I can't seem to find any way how to do this.

Comment: Please note that the `hashmap` tag should only be used for [Java's HashMap class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
bool operator<(const A& other) const{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(a[i][j]==other.a[i][j]) continue;
            return a[i][j]<other.a[i][j];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

That should work for the map. But it may be slow, if the array is big. Consider to write a hash function and use a unordered_map.